# How to limit images to move within the canvas for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am using GestureListener_DragDelta to enable 2 image to move up and down the canvas.

```
private void GestureListener_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        barTop.Y += e.VerticalChange;
        barTopTip.Y += e.VerticalChange;
    }
```

The images are set into a canvas. The height of the canvas is 1000. While both images are 100. How can I enable the images to move within the canvas only?

Answer (score 0):

i think canvas doesn't hide elements when they owerflow. Use border, grid instead

Comment: Hi @Cheese, I have tried using border and grid. However, it does not limit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer the following article, How achieve the Drag and Drop functionality in Windows Phone app.

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Drag_%26_Drop_in_Windows_Phone

It will guide you how to implement Drag and Drop functionality Step by Step.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @WmDev, thank you. However, I am using GestureListener. I am not using InteractionBehavior. I used GestureListener because I need to move both the images at the same time.